# Store function result or call it each time?

Tags: php

I have a class with a protected variable in it which can be get by a function `getVariable()`.

How much difference will it make if i'll call `getVariable()` every time instead of storing the result once and then use it? (the `getVariable()` does nothing more than `return $this->var`)

Comment: This can be tested. Write your code both ways, and run it several thousand times. Compare the run times to determine which is faster.

Comment: The only possible answer to this question is "benchmark it". Before you go through that trouble, I'd like to point out that the results don't matter. This kind of micro-optimization is pointless and counter productive. Write clear code. When it comes to PHP, *performance doesn't matter*.

Comment: Of course there is the overhead of a function call but that does not mean that you will experience a difference.

Comment: The time it took to write this post is thousands of times longer than the total combined time savings from using whichever is faster. (Not to mention the time it takes to write and run the benchmarks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not matter either way for you, premature optimization is bad. Do what makes sense design wise, not optimization wise. Either way, function/method calls in php are pretty cheap.